# Android Studio keeping an arrayList with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I am working on an application that will display a list of items to a user using fragments and listview. Currently, in my AlarmFragment1(), I have declared a private ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Alarms> alarms = new ArrayList<Alarms>
```

I use this list to populate a ListView in OnCreate with an AlarmAdapter I created. However, I want to be able to edit this list of alarms in other fragments, such as to delete an item.

In my AlarmFragment() I have an item listener that I use to open a new fragment where users get the option of deleting the item they clicked.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("item_index", i);

                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                DeleteAlarm fragment = new DeleteAlarm();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                transaction.add(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
```

Inside of my EditFragment I have a delete item button listener.

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Attempt at deleting item
                AlarmFragment alarm = new AlarmFragment();
                alarm.deleteAlarm(myInt); //<--myInt from bundle
                fListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
                fListener.changeFragment(3, "alarm");
            }
        });
```

I tried creating a public method inside of AlarmFragment() that would edit the list for me, such as:

```
public void remove(int i){ alarms.remove(i); }
```

Not only does this not work, but I also would have to think of a way to redisplay the listView that I originally made in OnCreateView(). I have been going in circles for quite a while now with no success. I also instead tried adding a new Alarm but even that didn't work. Is there some way I could do this or a different way of storing the array list since the list will be reset when the app is closed.

Comment: after removing item you need to notify adapter via notifyDataSetChanged method.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed hello, I tried adding the notifyDataSetChanged call inside of the public void remove() method, that however seems to still not work. My app just stops running and closes.

Comment: then you need to check the crash log as to why your app got crashed.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, ok I checked it. What I got was this: Argument rangeInElement (39,58) endOffset must not exceed descriptor text range (39, 58) length (19).
I'm not sure what this means. Could you please explain it

Answer (score 0):

A big part of your issue, is that you are creating a new `AlarmFragment` in the `onClick` function. You should be using the one that is still in the stack. As for your design, you should have the Activity holding the Array of Alarms, not the fragments. You can have the Activity, notify all its Fragments when the array data has changed, either through listeners, or direct call functions.

Comment: Ok, so I went ahead and did this. I added `FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                AlarmFragment fragment = (AlarmFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_alarm);
                //fragment.addAlarm(a);
                fragment.removeAlarm(myInt);` to the onClick, but it still dosen't work.

Comment: @JOhAnn How are you returning to the Alarm Fragment from the DeleteFragment? Are you popping the stack, or are you creating a new Fragment?

Comment: my AlarmFragment is part of a navigationBar so I use a switch case by id that I implement for it in my MainActivity to go back to it. I tried to use popBackStack(), but that wasn't working, so I have gone with using the switch instead, and I can't use replace because that would create a new AlarmFragment.

Comment: @JOhAnn So what does the switch yes do?